# Formalize the sentence: "Earth is the only planet inhabited by mathematicians"

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

I have to formalize the sentence:

> "Earth is the only planet inhabited by mathematicians"

Let:

- $P(x)$ stands for '*x* is a planet'
- $M(x)$ stands for '*x* is a mathematician'
- $I(x,y)$ stands for '*x* inhabits the planet *y*'
- $e$ stands for 'Earth' (a constant)

Is the following formalisation correct?

$P(e)\wedge\forall x\;((M(x)\wedge\exists y\: (P(y)\wedge I(x,y)))\rightarrow I(x,e))$

I interpreted the sentence in this way:

Earth is a planet and every mathematician that inhabits a planet necessarily inhabits the planet Earth.

Comment: That seems to leave open to the possibility that some (or perhaps all) mathematicians inhabit both Earth and Saturn. It also doesn't guarantee that there are any mathematicians to inhabit Earth at all.

Comment: @Henning: I'm not really sure that it is *intended* to guarantee that there are any mathematicians at all. That may be open to interpretation, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie: If there are no mathematicians, then in particular Earth is not inhabited by them, and if Earth is not a planet inhabited by mathematicians, then in particular it is not the _only_ such planet.

Comment: I had been interpreting it more or less as "an object is a planet inhabited by mathematicians only if the object is Earth." Still, your interpretation is compelling.

Comment: How should one interpret the plural "mathematicians"? That Earth is the only planet inhabited by two or more mathematicians; other planets may exist where one mathematician lives?

Comment: Can the problem of the existence of mathematicians be connected with the difference between this sentence and the sentence "Hearth is the only planet that can be inhabited by mathematicians"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement says that Earth is a planet and, if there is a mathematician that inhabits some planet, then said mathematician inhabits Earth.

This is very nearly what you need to say, but it doesn't quite get there on its own. After all, it doesn't rule out the possibility that one may inhabit multiple planets.

Instead, we should say that if there is a planet inhabited by mathematicians, then said planet is Earth. So, we would instead have $$\forall y\Bigl(\Bigl(\exists x\bigl(M(x)\wedge I(x,y)\bigr)\Bigr)\longrightarrow y=e\Bigl).$$

Note that this does *not* assert that Earth is a planet, nor that there are any mathematicians anywhere at all. Rather, it asserts (from a set-theoretic standpoint) that, if there is an element in the set of planets inhabited by at least one mathematician, then that element is Earth. Put more simply, $y$ is a planet inhabited by mathematicians only if $y$ is Earth.

There is some unfortunate ambiguity in the English language, so it may be that the speaker intended to say that Earth is a planet inhabited by mathematicians, and is the only such planet. However, that isn't really clear from their phrasing.

Comment: Is the $P(e)$ necessary?

Comment: @copper.hat: It seems to me that it isn't, after further thought. Take a look at my answer and see what you think.

Comment: I would have thrown a $P(y) \rightarrow \cdots$ in somewhere, but what I was originally wondering was if the statement implies existence.

Comment: I'm really not sure, to be honest. It seems like a uniqueness statement without a corresponding existence statement, but that's just my interpretation.

Comment: The language seems ambiguous. I would have written something like (assuming we have a notion of equality) $\forall p  (P(p) \rightarrow(\exists m ((M(m) \land I(m,p)) \rightarrow (p=e))))$.

Answer (score 2):

An object x is tested according to the following two criteria.

$\bullet$ P(x) = true if object x is a planet.

$\bullet$ M(x) = true if object x is inhabited by mathematicians.

The sentence can now be formalized. The following three versions are equivalent.

1. Search the set P is true, and if we find an x for which M(x) is true, then x is Earth.
2. Search the set M is true, and if we find an x for which P(x) is true, then x is Earth.
3. Search the set of all objects x, and if we find an x for which M(x) is true and P(x) is true, then x is Earth.